# Password Hide/Show Button only works one-way

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've build a little function which should change the content of a span, which lies in a `<td>` together with a button to the value of the button on the first push of the button. When the button is pushed again, it should replace the content with four asterisks.

Unfortunately, it only works one-way

```
$(".pw_show").click(function () {
  $(this).parent('td').children('span').html($(this).attr('value'));
  $(this).toggleClass('pw_hide pw_show');
});
$(".pw_hide").click(function () {
  $(this).parent('td').children('span').html("****");
  $(this).toggleClass('pw_hide pw_show');
});
```

Fiddle down here: http://jsfiddle.net/kXNk8/218/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You toggle the classes so you need to use dynamic event binding with `.on()` instead of `.click()`:

```
$('table').on('click',".pw_show", function () {
    $(this).parent('td').children('span').html($(this).attr('value'));
  $(this).toggleClass('pw_hide pw_show');
});
$('table').on('click',".pw_hide", function () {
    $(this).parent('td').children('span').html("****");
  $(this).toggleClass('pw_hide pw_show');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/fLgwLo6q/)**

After the first click, `.pw_show` no longer exists on the element which causes your issue.

Comment: Thanks to you too! It works as well, but the table-independent version given by Praveen Kumar suits my problem more.

Comment: @manniL - See my comment on the other answer as to why you shouldn't bind on the `document` and should use the `table`.

Comment: @j08691 What if the `<table>` was dynamic, and there are no other parents? `:)` - My question.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Thanks for the extra information

Comment: @PraveenKumar - *if* it were then sure, it then would not be the element to use.

Comment: @j08691 Thanks. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Delegating to a static element using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) will make it work or you should change it totally.

```
$(document).on("click", ".pw_show", function () {
  $(this).parent('td').children('span').html($(this).attr('value'));
  $(this).toggleClass('pw_hide pw_show');
});
$(document).on("click", ".pw_hide", function () {
  $(this).parent('td').children('span').html("****");
  $(this).toggleClass('pw_hide pw_show');
});
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4atrmks3/**

Comment: Whenever possible you should avoid binding to the document. In this case the table would've been a better choice. "Attaching many delegated event handlers near the top of the document tree can degrade performance. Each time the event occurs, jQuery must compare all selectors of all attached events of that type to every element in the path from the event target up to the top of the document. For best performance, attach delegated events at a document location as close as possible to the target elements. Avoid excessive use of document or document.body for delegated events on large documents."

Comment: @manniL What ^^^ says is right. Replace the `document` with a static parent, please. `:)`

Comment: @j08691 I know that, I should have mentioned... `:)` Thanks man. Since there was no other elements other than `<table>`, what can we do?

Answer (score -1):

You should really just toggle the attribute for `type` between `password` and `text` not use a placeholder.

```js
var password = false;

$('a').click(function(){
    if (!password){
       password = true;
       $('input').attr('type', 'password');
    } else {
       password = false;
       $('input').attr('type', 'text');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="text">
<a href="#">Click to toggle password / text</a>
```

Comment: The password is not inside an input field, so this is not an option